# Route Parameter Subscription not triggered reliably in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I'm developing an Angular2 based quiz with a few 'static' components (home, faq, etc) and a component that represents the quiz cards.
My setup uses a route with a placeholder just like this:

```
{
  path: 'quiz/:questionPage',
  component: QuizComponent
},
```

Here `questionPage` is supposed to be numeric...

And to switch quiz cards I'm changing the location and show the new card:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'
...
constructor (
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private location: Location) {...}
...
showQuestion(next) {
  this.location.go ('quiz/' + next);
  this.showQuestion (next);
}
```

To implement browser back/forward in the `QuizComponent` (besides the next/prev in the quiz cards) I thought I could just just subscribe to the route's parameter in the `QuizComponent`'s constructor:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  console.log ("found params: ", params);
});
```

That's been working like a charm: clicking next/prev updated the cards and with the browsers back/forward I am able to go through the history of cards. All perfect I thought, but I just discovered that there is at least one use case that does not work:

**If I go back (no matter how often) and then click something new** the back button does only update the location (url in addressbar) but **the above subscription is not fired** (and thus the card won't get updated). If I click back one more time it's working fine again, but I'm then 2 steps back!? I can go forward again to access the correct entry in the history, but that's of course annoying...

So.. Am I doing something wrong? Maybe that's also a super-stupid approach to implement browser-back/forward?

Comment: Normally I would use the Router to navigate instead of Location, not sure though it would make a difference in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, after reading the documentation for [Location](https://angular.io/api/common/Location) I assume this is indeed the problem. This is a service for interacting with the browsers URL, you should use the [Router](https://angular.io/api/router/Router) for navigation inside your apps.

As stated in the documentation also:

> Use Location only if you need to interact with or create normalized
>   URLs outside of routing.

So if you navigate with something like:

```
this.router.navigate(['quiz', next]);
```

it should work as expected.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot, really! :)